# How can I extract all rows in one file if their position is less than in another file in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have one file of genomic coordinates (file 1) and another file of variants with their locations (file 2). I want to extract all of the rows where the variant locations fall within the range of the genomic coordinates in file 1. I tried to subset the files in R, but I can't seem to get it. Essentially, I want all of the variants that fall within the range of the genomic coordinates in file 1. Thanks for assistance if anyone can help!!

```
p <- read.csv("new_chr1.csv", header = TRUE)
vars <- read.csv("../variants.csv", header=T)
t1 <- subset(p, vars$cnvStart > p$chrStart & vars$cnvEnd < p$chrEnd)``
```

file 1:

```
chr Start End Number
chr1    12001  13000      2
chr1    13000  13000     10
chr1    13010  14000      6
chr1    13020  15000      2
chr1    14000  15000     10
chr1    15000  15000      4
chr1    15300  16000     12
chr1    13000  51000      1
chr1    48000  52000      1
chr1    51000  52000      4
```

file 2:

```
variant  chr  chrStart chrEnd cpg    gene
var128   1    13467   13499   cg27611665   FBXL12  
var229   1    48117   48334   cg27611665   FBXL12 
var509   1    568289  568419  cg2511665    FBXL12
var213   1    186392  186392  cg2558303    SLC25A4
var999   1    401909  401963  cg27472032   VPS39
var122   1    182444  182494  cg2743794    FXR1
var098   1    602184  602248  cg27398547   C14orf39
var876   1    157302  157344  cg27355746   UBTF
var287   1    163665  163709  cg2752122    PHF20L1`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the second column of the second file is the start site, the third column is the end site, and that you want all of the range to fall within at least one of the ranges present in the first file, on the same chromosome (which I'm assuming is in the first column of the second file).

If so, this should work:

```
file1 = read.table("file1.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
file2 = read.table("file2.txt", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
file1$chr_num = as.numeric(gsub("chr", "", file1$chr))
in_range <- function(chr_num, chr_start, chr_stop){
  chr_matches = file1[file1$chr_num == as.numeric(chr_num), ]
  res = any(as.numeric(chr_start) > chr_matches$Start & as.numeric(chr_stop) < chr_matches$End)
  return(res)
}
apply(file2, 1, function(x) in_range(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

With the result:

```
TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

EDIT: Forgot the last step; if you want to use this to subset the variant file, then you can use this:

```
variants_to_keep = apply(file2, 1, function(x) in_range(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
variants_in_range = file2[variants_to_keep, ]
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The first column is the chromosome, second is the start site and third is the end site. I actually have all of the files separated by chromosome, I thought I could just do it per file. I will definitely give this a try. Thank you Andy!!!!!

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it now.

Comment: Andy, I'm trying to understand the function. What is the "1" for in apply function()?

Comment: That's the `MARGIN` parameter of `apply`. From function help:   MARGIN 
a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns. Where X has named dimnames, it can be a character vector selecting dimension names.

Comment: Oh. Ok. thank you pbahr!! Its still running as of now. very large files.

Comment: It seemed to timeout Andy. I started it over with a smaller file and with the above edits.